# How do I construct this random effect model in R?

Tags: r, mixed-models, random-effects

I have a biomedical data named `data1`, and I want to construct a random effect model to analyze 'eGFR'(a continuous variable), there are four covariates I am interested in this study, 'sex', 'diabetes state', 'smoking state', 'treatment time'.

If I want to assume this four factors to be fixed effect, and the intercept to be random effect, how do I construct this mixed effect model in R language?

For example, I want to write this type :

```
lme(eGFR~sex+diabetes+smoking+time, random=???, data=data1)
```

Comment: I think you want `random = ~1|indiv` where `indiv` is the column which identifies individuals in your data.

Comment: Thank you.

I have another question, the same example, 

if I assume 'smoking', 'time' and intercept to be random effect,

and 'sex' and 'diabetes' to be fixed effect,

how do I construct the mixed effect model in R?

Comment: `~sex+diabetes|indiv` and now it is time for you to read some documentation.

Comment: Thank you, I have no to find the example for the multiple covariates in mixed effect model, and I know how to do this now, thanks!